# I don't understand "%K == %@" or "active == %@" in NSPredicate statements

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm going through a Core Data book on a chapter about fetching data. It has the following code:

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "name", "Dark Side of The Moon")
```

`K` is referring to `"name"` and `@` to `"Dark Side of The Moon"` to my understanding, but are `%K` and `%@` reserved words? Is there a difference between `K` and `@`? Can I use any letters or just these two?

Is this unique just to entities and attributes? I thought to put variables we use the `\()` format inside print statements for example, but I'm confused here.

Is there a reference for this in the Swift programming guide?

Searching for `%` and `@` in Google doesn't seem to work so I couldn't find clear information on this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: The above link is also shown in the documentation for [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/). Always start by looking at the class documentation.

Comment: The class documentation doesn't have it, but the link @TylerP provided contains the answer if you pay attention: "%@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.", "%K is a var arg substitution for a key path."

Comment: @lazarevzubov The class documentation has a link to the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) which includes the link by TylerP.

Comment: The main page of the guide, but not the bit that @TylerP pointed out. Anyway, I agree to accept my defeat in this links battle, but it doesn't change the fact that the Predicate Format String Syntax documentation answers your question.